# Only accept HTTP connections from Localhost in Go?

Tags: linux, http, go, tcp, localhost

I have a simple HTTP Server standing up in Golang:

```
h := http.NewServeMux()
h.Handle("/somepath", MyHandler)

s := &http.Server{
    Addr:    "1234",
    Handler: h,
}   

s.ListenAndServe();
```

What is the best way to drop connections where the caller is not localhost?  Currently I'm considering inspecting the underlying connection information and ensuring that the IP Address is `127.0.0.1`, but this wastes a whole lot of resources (and runs through a whole bunch of Go code) before ultimately dropping the connection.  Ideally, I can instrument the Golang server to drop the initial TCP SYN packet based on IP Address, and not create a TCP connection at all (or reveal that this port is listening).

What's the cleanest path forward here?

Comment: The cleanest path to literally do what you're asking is to use the host firewall. Go doesn't see the TCP SYN packet, that's handled by the operating system,

Comment: @JimB So could I (from Go running on Linux) shell out and create an IPTable rule or something before I bind and listen on my port?

Comment: Why not `http.ListenAndServe("localhost:80", nil)`? That would bind the service to localhost only.

Comment: @VonC If that is the answer, then I would accept it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Converting [`VonC`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s comment into an answer.

You can bind the host by setting `host:port` in your `http.Server.Addr` or `http.ListenAndServe`.

They use `net.Listen` internally.

From [`net.Listen`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#Listen) :

> For TCP and UDP, the syntax of laddr is "host:port", like
>   "127.0.0.1:8080". If host is omitted, as in ":8080", Listen listens on
>   all available interfaces instead of just the interface with the given
>   host address.